# Showing notification only once after every refresh

Tags: javascript, notifications

what i wanted to do is only show the notification after the notification allowed.

what i have right now is, every after refresh on page it is always showing the notifications

this is my javascript

```
function notifyMe() {

        function AutoRefresh( t ) {
            setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
        }
        // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
        if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
        }

        // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
        else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            // If it's okay let's create a notification
            var notification = new Notification('{!! $myname->body !!}');
            notification.onclick = function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
                window.open('http://localhost:8000/spektra/spektra-memberikan-aneka-tawaran-di-jakarta-fair-kemayoran-2018', '_blank');
            }
        }

        // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
        else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
            Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
            // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification('{!! $myname->body !!}');
                notification.onclick = function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
                window.open('http://localhost:8000/spektra/spektra-memberikan-aneka-tawaran-di-jakarta-fair-kemayoran-2018', '_blank');
            }
            }
            });
        }
        }
```

what should i do to make the notification only once, even after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You have to track if the user has already seen the notification and, if so, skip the rest of your `notifyMe` function. For example, you could store the information in `localStorage`.

```
function notifyMe() {
  function AutoRefresh(t) {
    // passing strings to setTimeout makes me shiver
    // too many years of avoiding eval and stuff i guess :)
    setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, t);
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem('userHasSeenNotification')) {
    return; // early return, exits the function
  }

  if (!('Notification' in window)) {
    alert('Notifications ... ');
    return; // early return, lets us get rid of the "else"
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // save seen state
    localStorage.setItem('userHasSeenNotification', 1);

    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification('{!! $myname->body !!}');
    notification.onclick = function(event) {
       event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
       window.open('http://localhost:8000/spektra/spektra-memberikan-aneka-tawaran-di-jakarta-fair-kemayoran-2018', '_blank');
    };
    return; // ... again ...
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    // save seen state
    localStorage.setItem('userHasSeenNotification', 1);

    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification('{!! $myname->body !!}');
        notification.onclick = function(event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
          window.open('http://localhost:8000/spektra/spektra-memberikan-aneka-tawaran-di-jakarta-fair-kemayoran-2018', '_blank');
        };
      }
     });
   }
 }
}
```

Hint: You might want to move that last `localStorage.setItem` call into the callback passed to `.then(function (permission) { ... })`.

Comment: but i use this for just a guest only, so i have no user information on who saw the notifications

Comment: it's not necessary that the user "logs in" to something. `localStorage` is a store build right into the browser, that allows to store information on the client side. you can read more about it at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: this doesn't work for me, anything else? i put the whole code. its not showing anything sadly

Comment: What does not work? Do you get messages in the console? Have you tried the `debugger` statement to identify at which point it fails? And: In case you once denied notifications while testing, have you _reset your permissions_ in the browser settings? **EDIT** Also, the initial value of `Notification.permission` is neither `"granted"` nor `"denied"`, it is `"default"` and you don't have any `if`-statement for that.